# How to not allow anything above a div (text, other elements, etc.)

Tags: html, css

I created a logo that i want to place at the top of my webpage. Obviously, when I put any other text into the page, it is inserted at the top of the page and moves the logo down. Is there any way to make sure that nothing is inserted above the logo?

logo div CSS `#div_logo {
             visibility: show;
             position: fixed;
             width: 70%;
             left: 50%;
             margin-left: -32.5%;
             clear: both;
             padding: 10px;
            }`

Thanks!

Comment: Easy.. don't put any html content above the logo div.

Comment: Could you post a fiddle pls?

Comment: I have posted my answer with a fiddle.Please do check it out.If it meets up with your requirement,please do accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:- In your existing code of CSS(which you mentioned in the question),please do add the z-index with which it will acheiv your requirement.
    `z-index:9999` in your css file.

I have added a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shadowstrike/T7tbw/4/)** here.Please do check it out.Change the path name of your image and then give it a shot.

HTML:-

```
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<div id="div_logo">
  <img src="someimage.png" width="100px" height="140px" />
</div>
<p>Because the image has a z-index of 9999, it will be placed on top of  the text.</p>
```

CSS:-

```
#div_logo
{
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 z-index:9999;
 background-color:red;
 width:100px;
 height:140px;
}
```